PostgreSQL SET session_replication_role = replica not bypassing constraints in Supabase seed file
I'm trying to seed data into my Supabase database but even though my seed.sql (generated by Supabase) includes SET session_replication_role = replica at the top, constraints are still being enforced. I verified through logs that the replication role successfully changes to 'replica' (SELECT current_setting('session_replication_role') shows 'replica'), but my check constraint rounds_end_time_check still blocks the inserts.

You'll need to drop the NOT NULL and CHECK constraints to lift them, even if you mean that to be temporary.
They aren't enforced by triggers the way foreign key, unique and exclude are (and obviously constraint triggers) so they aren't affected by either session_replication_role or alter table t1 disable trigger all; and cannot be deferred with set constraints.
It's possible to make a check constraint not valid, but it'll still be checked for all incoming rows after that.
demo at db<>fiddle
create table test(id int not null);
alter table test disable trigger all;
insert into test values(null);


ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "test" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null).


create table test(id int check (id>3));
alter table test disable trigger all;
insert into test values(2);


ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_id_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2).


create table test(id int);--ok
insert into test values(1);--ok
alter table test --ok despite id=1 present
  add constraint id_gt_3 check (id>3) not valid;
insert into test values(2);--error


ERROR:  new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "id_gt_3"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2).


It's also generally faster if you populate bare, unlinked and unconstrained tables first, and only build the indexes and add constraints after that.
